# MediaPlayer plugin causing the app to crash

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-studio-2.2

When I use MediaPlayer plugin in my code and deploy it on either emulator or Android device, the build finishes without errors but the app crashes on startup on the devices.

> Java: MainActivity.java

```
package com.oniichan.launchpadify;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clap1);

    public void clapone(View v){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Playing clap1.wav", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

> XML: activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.oniichan.launchpadify.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150px"
            android:layout_height="150px"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/play1"
            android:onClick="clapone"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problematic line is

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clap1);
```

If I comment out the above line in the program, everything seems to work fine. Only when I uncomment the above line in an anticipation of something good to happen, the app crashes. Here are screenshots of the app

[Application Layout in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoV68.png)

[Application Crash on Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUPKP.png)

To keep things clean I put the crash log in pastebin
lookup here: `pastebin.com/NGrqTmAf`

Comment: In case you are wondering, yes the square in the top left corner is a button which I am using to play sound

Comment: There has to be a crash report in the Logcat (Android Monitor) What does it say there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

> final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clap1);

is executed before the Activity is completely instantiated, so `this` does not yet exist.

If you want to have the `MediaPlayer` as a member variable, leave out the `final` and do it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clap1);
    }

    // other code here...
}
```